# Responses JSON with Relationship - Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: laravel, rest, api, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm working on a Laravel project and I want to create a REST API for a website. On my system, I have two tables:

Blogs and Categories. The table blogs have the category_id column, which is a key that references the column ID in the category table.

Blogs Migration

```
class CreateBlogsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
     Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('title');
     $table->longtext('body');
     $table->string('category_id');
     $table->timestamps();
    });
   }
   .....
}
```

Categories Migration

```
class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
     Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('name');
     $table->timestamps();
    });
   }
   ....
}
```

My blogs Model

```
class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'category_id'];
    public function category() {
       return $this->hasMany('app\Category');
    }
}
```

My blogs Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function blog() {
       return $this->hasMany('app\Blog');
    }
}
```

So, I created a BlogController and configured the routes to access the corresponding API function.

The api / blogs / via GET is for the index function of my controller, and the function looks like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $blog = Blog::all();
    return response()->json($blog, 200);
}
```

With this, I can get the data from the blogs table

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "title from my blog",
        "text": "text body here",
        "category_id": "2",
        "created_at": "2018-09-05 21:08:21",
        "updated_at": "2018-09-05 21:08:21"
    }
]
```

but I would like to merge the table of blogs and categories, and get a similar response to this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "title from my blog",
        "text": "text body here",
        "category_id": "2",
        "created_at": "2018-09-05 21:08:21",
        "updated_at": "2018-09-05 21:08:21"
        "category": [{
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Development"
        }]
    }
]
```

someone to help?

Comment: `category` has to be a `BelongsTo` relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You are using hasMany relation without a reference id for blog in categories table, so the datas were not eager loaded. If you change the migration as

```
 class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
  {
     public function up()
     {
       Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->string('name');
         $table->timestamps();
         $table->integer('category_id');
      });
    }
   ....
  }
```

and then you can use

```
Blog::with('category')->get();
```

Or change the relationship as

```
public function category(){
 return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

and use

```
Blog::with('category')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the relationship and it will be included in the serialized response.

```
$blog = Blog::with('category')->get();
```

This example is eager loading the category relation.

I suggest you read through the eloquent relationships docs:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: i already tried and I get this error: "Call to undefined relationship [categories] on mode [App\Blog]."

Comment: I updated my answer already, read my note, your relation is named category.

Comment: I have already renamed both categories, but i get this error "Class 'app\Category' not found." 
something else is wrong

Comment: Is your namespace `app` or `App`?

Comment: I fixed my namespace app for App, and it's almost la ... if I make $ category = Category :: with ('blogs') -> get (); I get my list of categories and within each category I have the blogs of that particular category, but that's not exactly what I want. I want to consult my blog list, and get the NAME of each category from each blog, as I mentioned in the question. and at the moment if I make $ blog = with ('categories') -> get () I get the blog list but with "categories": null

Comment: in summary, I want to get category name when browsing my blogs.

Comment: You have quite a few issues here, I think you need to re-read the docs I linked.  Your structure does not match your relationships.

Comment: I was able to display the category name in the blog listing, but how do I remove the category name after registering a new blog in the database?

Comment: Why would you remove a category name in that scenario?  I'm not sure what you're asking but I'm pretty sure if you read the docs, you'll find the answer.

Comment: I've been able to solve the problem in question, but now I'm facing another similar problem.

to return a response with category name, I have already read the documentation, it does not say how to return a response in the controller

my store function to register a new blog
$ blog = new Blog ($ request-> all ());
$ blog-> save ();
return response () -> json ($ blog, 200);

so I need to return this blog with: with ('category') -> get () too

Comment: return response()->json($blog->with('category'), 200); does not work

Comment: It definitely is covered in the docs, you're really asking too much on this site and you've extended beyond the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, I just needed to say that the blog belongs to a category, and a category can have several blogs

```
class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'category_id',];
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Category Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function blogs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Blog');
    }
}
```

So to list blogs with category details

```
public function index()
{
    $blogs = Blog::with('category')->get();
    return response()->json($blogs, 200);
}
```

So to list the categories with your blogs

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('blogs')->get();
    return response()->json($categories, 200);
}
```